# Backuping files before change

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Since Ansible backup feature is questionable a little with lack of configuration. I'm looking into some solution.

Normally in script I would have backup function that you can call with file name and it would copy the file to separate location with changed name.. for example bkp_location = /tmp/backup//

Lets say I want to backup /etc/systemconf/network I pass it to function and it would copy it to backup directory under etc_systemconf_network ( it replace / with _ so we can tell where it come from )

What would be the best solution in Ansible for something like that ? That I could call it in every role etc...

Maybe one backup.yml in root directory and have it include and pass variable ( file name ) to it, would that work ?

**Edit:**

Backup feature I speak of:

there is an option **backup: yes** for some modules ( this is shared function between them as far as I know ) but does not offer any modification to what it does.

Like what would be the backup file name, where it would be located... ? so I have to handle that externally... kind of mid-step between.. but seems like include backup.yml and pass variable to it will do the trick.

Comment: `ansible backup feature` => can you please describe which exact feature your are referring to ? The one I'm thinking of right now is the possibility to save a backup file when using the `copy` or `template` modules for example. But ansible is not a backup solution and does not have an overall "backup feature". What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: Hi, @Zeitounator.. yes that's the one, there is an option backup: yes for some modules ( this is shared function between them as far as I know ) but does not offer any modification to what it does. Like what would be the backup file name, where it would be located... ? so I have to handle that externally... kind of mid-step between.. but seems like include backup.yml and pass variable to it will do the trick.

Comment: Please add this as an edit to your question. Comments are highly volatile and might disappear. And one should be able to understand the subject by reasons your question only.

Answer (score 2):

cat backup.yml

```
- name: creating backup
  copy: src="{{ path_of_file }}" dest="{{ bkp_location }}/backup{{ path_of_file }}{{ contenttoaddwhilebackingup }}" remote_src=true
```

in running playbook

```
include: backup.yml
```

So if you run a playbook like this

```
ansible-playbook random.yml -e 'bkp_location=/tmp/backup/ path_of_file=/etc/systemconf/network contenttoaddwhilebackingup=26march2021'
```

It will create backup like this

```
ls -lrt /etc/systemconf/
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 Mar 25 15:22 network

ls -lrt /tmp/backup/
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 Mar 25 15:22 backupnetwork26march2021
```